# There are 100 marbles: 35 red, 15 green ,30 blue, 20 black. Twenty people choose a marble with replacement

Tags: probability, statistics

I was hoping to get assistance in solving this problem.

We have 100 marbles in an urn: 35 red, 15 green, 30 blue, and 20 black. Twenty people randomly chose a marble, noted it's color, and put it back in the urn. What is the probability that an equal number of each color is selected?

Approach: There are a total of 4 colors, so an equal number of each color would be 5 marbles of every color. Seems to be unordered sampling with replacement.

I believe it can be solved as followed:

$(35/100)^5(15/100)^5(30/100)^5(20/100)^5$

As we want to get 5 drawn of each color. Am I on the right track? I am questioning my approach.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to account for the fact that they can be chosen in any order. I think you need the multinomial function.

Comment: I think you have a good start.  Now how many permutations of the selectors are there.  $\frac {20!}{5!5!5!5!}$